# Component as property with omitted arguments

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I would like to define a property which has to be a component with omitted properties.

I have a validation component with some properties:

```
interface ValidationProps {
    value: string,
    check: Array<(value) => boolean>
}

const Validation: FC<ValidationProps> = function(){}
export default Validation;
```

And I have an input component.

```
interface InputProps {
    value: string,
    onChange: (e: SyntaticEvent) => void,
    validations: ???
}

const Input: FC<InputProps> = function(props){
    return <span>
        <input value={props.value} onChange={props.onChange} />
        {React.cloneElement(props.validations, {value})}
    </span>
}
export default Input;
```

So I would like to define that InputProps.validations has to be a Validation but with omitted value prop.

It should be used like that:

```
<Input value="value" onChange={...} validations={<Validation check={[(value) => value != null, (value) => value.length <= 5]} />} />
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not *entirely* clear to me what you want to achieve here, so there may be something I have missed...

But you cannot directly specify that the prop must be a component with specific properties. You *can*, however specify `validations: Omit<ValidationProps, 'value'/>`, and then instead of `{React.cloneElement(props.validations, {value})}` simply instantiate your `<Validation check={props.validations} value={value}/>` inside the input

UPDATE:

If you do not want a dependency between the two components (Input and Validation), you cannot have a dependency between the props interfaces either, unless you share these into a third module, which is imported by both.

In that case, you could abstract even further and let validations be a render prop like `validations: (value) => ReactElement`. This could then be used much like in your original but with added "fat arrow" syntax

```
<Input value="value" onChange={...} validations={() => <Validation check={[(value) => value != null, (value) => value.length <= 5]} />} />
```

Instead of `cloneElement`, this would be instantiated simply by calling `validations(value)`.

This *does* abstract it to the point of too much flexibility, since anything can be injected into the validation render prop.

Comment: `<Validation check={props.validations} value={value}/>` is definitly the way, how this should work. The advantage of React.cloneElement is, that I do not need to import Validation in Input. So if I dont need Validation in a project, it is not imported. My problem is that I got an error that value is missing in `validations={<Validation`  <--- because it is defined for the Validation Component.

Comment: You did state "So I would like to define that InputProps.validations has to be a Validation but with omitted value prop.", which very much implies a dependency between the two. I have added an update to the answer

Comment: Yes, there is a dependency from Input to Validation, but only if needed. Validation can be used by its own, so it has no dependency to Input. For example another Component like Dropdown can also have a dependency to Validation. Components enrich the props with value for the Validation component to work. As you mentioned in your update there is a dependency from Input to Validation, but this dependency is gone after converting from tsx to jsx. Actual I try component overload. Maybe Input.validations could be like `validations: ReactElement<Omit<ValidationProps, "value">, typeof Validation>`

Comment: Wouldn't that still give you the problem that the actual `Validation` *needs* a value, and thus cannot be instantiated to be passed into `validations`?

Comment: I am beginning to think that perhaps you should reconsider the design altogether. It seems to me that having the `Input` concerning itself with validation is a breach of the Single Responsibility Principle. Rather, the `Input` could provide an `errorMessage` prop (or similar),  which could provide any validation feedback. The validation itself could then be handled by the consuming page/component by wiring up the `onChange` method to validation and passing any validation feedback back to the `errorMessage`